# Return audit date to date type 110

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write a query that will return the 'Audit Date' field as MM-DD-YYYY.  I searched a few forums, but can only find how to convert the current date in that format.  How do I return all dates in this format?

Here is what I found to convert the current date:

```
convert(varchar, getdate(), 110)
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the msdn doc for [Convert and Cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx)

```
SELECT convert(varchar, [audit date], 110) as audit_date
FROM [your table here]
```

Comment: Beautiful!  Thank you!  I'll accept the answer as soon as the site lets me.